# Extending coreplot to draw Gauge Chart and Perot Charts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

Is there a way to extend coreplot library to create Gauge chart and Perot Chart? Could someone please point me in the right direction.Or is there any other library available to achieve the same.

Comment: Can you link to some examples, so I can get a picture how these plot/chart types would look like?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass `CPTPlot` and create a custom plot types. Look at the existing plots to see the required structure. The most important parts are the data loading and drawing methods.

Comment: Thank you! Extending core plot was tough. I have implemented the guage chart on my own using the CGContextAddArc and [UIBezierPath+arrow](https://gist.github.com/mayoff/4146780)